# Why do you need to fill the first element of array when implementing heap?

Tags: data-structures, heaps

I'm looking at Heap data structure implementation from different sources. What I found is that sometimes it's implemented with the first element of array set to magic (default, unused?) value.

For example [here](https://github.com/ngenerics/ngenerics/blob/master/Source/NGenerics/DataStructures/General/Heap.cs#L129) the first element is added in constructor.

And visualization [here](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/Heap.html) shows that it's also set to something magic.

However, I've seen many examples without the first element. What's the trick and why sometimes it's there and sometimes it's not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not *some magic* element but $-\infty$, which is because this is min-heap, in max-heap it would be $\infty$.
The sole purpose is consistent representation of all elements inserted - it guarantees that the next element can be compared and it will be smaller (or bigger - for appropriate heap type) - just to avoid checking whether inserted element is the first one or not and then it would be compared to existing ones. In this form you avoid something like *isEmpty* everytime you insert element, so it saves time, redundant function calls and (rather unwanted) conditional statement at the cost of one element called "guardian" or sometimes "terminator" (popular name in the lists where you check for this element instead of some NULL or *isEnd*).

Comment: Here is how adding to heap looks like without the first element:

https://gist.github.com/ro31337/bedeb9b3edffa96b2338328e82426454

Where is conditional statement at the cost of one element here?

Source taken from https://habrahabr.ru/post/112222/ . How it will be different _with_ the first element?

Comment: $i > 0 &&$, to lazy eval possibility of the non-existence of two compared elements. With the guardian the check will not be present and the parent will be the guardian.